# How to schedule send/receive in Outlook for Mac using Exchange Account

Tags: ms-office, office-365

How can I turn off automatic incoming emails and instead receive new emails on a schedule only? For example, new emails at 10AM and 2PM.

**Version:** Outlook for Mac 16.13.1
**Server Type:** outlook.office365.com Exchange Server

Comment: You'll need VBA to accomplish this - are you comfortable with that?

Comment: Yes, I don't really like basic, but willing to do the needful

Comment: So sorry... I spoke too soon. I knew that VBA was sandboxed on Mac, but I've just learned that Outlook for Mac does not support VBA - at all. And apparently Outlook for Mac doesn't have the command line "switches" that its Windows counterpart does. Ah! Now here's an idea: I'll post an "answer" stating this isn't possible... if that's wrong - or if there's any way at all to do it, that will bring them to the fore :)

Comment: And +1 for a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this. VBA would be the obvious choice, but Outlook for Mac does not support it. Another (crude) approach would be to start and stop Outlook from `crontab` entries with the appropriate command line switches, but Outlook for Mac doesn't have command line switches either.